# Fetch more and more data in a single row and five column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fetch data in table format single row and five columns and I have limited the tabular column up to 5 columns. Let's say query fetches more than 5 data like 20 or 15 data etc. Displaying this much of data in a single row looks very bad. What I am trying to do is that after fetching 5 data from database in table single row and five column. User should have facility to look next 5 data in the same row by clicking on the button without reloading the page.
Like on this page: http://www.flipkart.com/
Here is what I have written:

```
$connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root","") or die(mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_select_db($connect,'db') or die(mysqli_connect_error());
$quer y= mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * from table where name like 'Groc%'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  if ($row['discount'] != 0) {
    $local_price = ($row['discount'] / 100) * $row['price'];
    $row['price'] = $row['price'] - $local_price;
  } else {
    $local_price = 0;
  }
  echo '
<td style="height=100px">
  <center>
    <a href="">
      <img src="' . $row['image'] . '" width="150px" height="150px" />
    </a>
    <center>
    <figcaption>
      &#8360; ' . $row['price'] . '
    </figcaption>
    </center>
    <center>
      <figcaption>
        Save: &#8360; ' . $local_price . ' (' . $row['discount'] . '%)
      </figcaption>
    </center>
    <center>
      <figcaption>
        In stock: ' . $row['stock'] . '
      </figcaption>
    </center>
  </center>
  <figcaption>
    <center>
      <button class="button button1">
        <img src="../images/Add-to-cart-128.png" width="20px" height="20px">
        Add to cart
      </button>
      <a href="">
        <button class="button button2">
          <img src="../images/vector_65_07-128.png" height="20px";width="20px">
          Buy Now
        </button>
      </a>
    </center>
  </figcaption>
</td>
  ';
}
```

Any help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you share your code so far or is it the one driving the page  http://www.flipkart.com/?

Comment: I guess it uses javascript. And i don't have any idea about javascript. So i posted.

Comment: If you share your code in the question, you increase the chances that someone will be able to find a solution for you.

Comment: if you are going to get the next 5 posts let's say from php file then add them into another div and show them to user you gonna need ajax if you are going to hide 10 out of 15 then on button click hide only 5 and display 10 it's very simple by javascript

Comment: @Ahmadghoneim Since i have no idea about javascript or ajax can you please tell me where should i start.

Comment: ajax is part of javaScript you can use JQuery which is a javaScript library which is very easy to use there is easy tutorial on w3schools about jquery and how to use it on your website